# Find index of items in combox visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, controls

I am trying to set customer details on form load and have run in to an issue when ensuring a combobox is set to the right index.

```
For iIndex As Integer = 0 To (Me.combo.Items.Count - 1)

    If Me.combo.Items(iIndex).Key = customer.CustTypeId Then
        Me.combo.SelectedIndex = iIndex
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

The Items.Key comes from a Klik control that I am trying to convert to a standard ComboBox. I have tried accessing the RowId of the Item but to no avail.

Can anyone suggest how to accomplish the above?

Comment: what is "the issue"?  that should work unless the Key is not found, case mismatch etc

Comment: The Key isnt found. Key is a property on the Klik control but doesnt exist for standard ComboBox's as far as I can see. I am pretty new to VB so apologies if this is obvious

Comment: if you are just putting strings in the CBO, use `If Me.combo.Items(iIndex) = customer.CustTypeId...` in the test.  Key was apparently on the other thing you are replacing

Comment: Me.combo.Items(iIndex) is a DataRowView, I can't compare that directly to an int

Comment: you might want to include these kinds of important details to your questions. in that case, cast it and use the relevant value in the comparison

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the Collection.IndexOf method?

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim one As String = "one"
        Dim two As String = "two"
        Dim three As String = "three"
        Dim four As String = "four"
        Dim five As String = "five"

        ComboBox1.Items.Add(one)
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(two)
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(three)
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(four)
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(five)

        MsgBox(ComboBox1.Items.IndexOf("three"))

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: DataRowView doesn't have an IndexOf method sadly :(